# Is there a way to show a static card that is inserted?

Tags: google-gdk

I have the user do something in my GDK app, then they are done and I want to put a summary card into the timeline.  I can insert the card using TimelineManager.insert(card) but the user has no idea it's there.  It would be nice if I could insert the card, kill the GDK app and leave the user off at the card I inserted.  Any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently supported by our APIs but please file a feature request on our [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list).

Answer (score 0):

Note that this has been filed as Issue 311 "Static Card published through GDK doesn't reveal (focus) automatically", so if you would like to vote on it, you can star the issue at https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=311